# EntityManager using Spring ( Null Pointer Exception )

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

im getting null on EntityManager  and i just dont know why ?

my web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
</listener>
```

my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="pl.wisecode.controller" />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" 
destroy-method="close">
    <!-- Connection properties -->
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/wiseCode" />
    <property name="user" value="wiseCode" />
    <property name="password" value="asseronia1" />
    <!-- Pool properties -->
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3000" />
    <property name="loginTimeout" value="300" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="pl.wisecode.model" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

and my DAO looks like this

```
public class UserDAO {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
public void dodajUuser(User user) {
    entityManager.merge(user);
}
```

}

Im sory for a lot of code ! :( im new to spring and i just dont know why im getting null at entityManager, if someone could give me some tips about it or show me where i make mistake i would be really grateful !
ps. i dont have any persistence.xml is it necessary ? and if it is where should i put it ?

Comment: How do you create `UserDAO`?

Comment: I just use new operator in my controller. UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();

Comment: Then thats your problem. You need to let Spring manage the component